# I'm trying to merge rows when adjacent data is blank

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a report and the Work Order numbers are in column A and the locations are located in column B; however, the address is put on multiple rows and the Work Order number is only on the first row.  Some work orders only have one line addresses while others have multiple.  I want to condense the multiple lines for the locations to one I can use CONCATENATE(B2, " ", B3), but I do not know how to add the if column A is blank then CONCATENATE(B2, " ", B3).  Any recommendations are appreciated.

```
+------------------+------------------------------+
|     Work Order # |          Location            |
+------------------+------------------------------+
|     1600374-02   | Location 159 7/14/15         |
|                  | 123 Whatever Rd.             |
|     1600374-03   | Location 123 7/14/15         |
|                  | 555 Need excel Help Fast Dr. |
|     1603504-03   | Location 999                 |
+------------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(A3="",B2& " " & B3,B2))
```

It first tests whether the Cell in Column A of the same row is empty, if so it puts and empty string.

If not it test whether the next row is blank, if so it concatenates the two lines, if not it just puts the one row.

[image]

Comment: ..........clever approach...........